# Increase Homestead Mysql Buffer Size

Tags: mysql, homestead

I'm wondering how can we increase the buffer size in mysql using Homestead? I have successfully installed my application using Homestead and PHP 5.6 using Apache. Now when running my application I run into buffer size issue and it seems I need to increase this size. How can we achieve this in Homestead?

Answer (score -1):

Yon can increase it by `'sort_buffer_size'` on  `[yourappname]/config/database.php`

return array(

```
/* other settings removed for brevity */
'connections' => array(


    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'database',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'options'   => array(
            'sort_buffer_size' => '100M', //set the value as desired
            //other options you want to set
        ),
    ),
    /* other connections removed for brevity */
)
)
```

Comment: I don't have that file in my application. I'm looking for the actual configuration if available in Homestead or the Mysql inside the box. It seems this fix is application level

Comment: @MadzQuestioning
find database configuration file and configs. try to change it.